# About the Probability problem which Fermat and Pascal Talked about

Tags: probability, solution-verification

While looking for problems with probabilities, I tried a recurrence sequence. The problem was this:

> Pascal and Fermat were playing the game with $10,000$ dollars each. The rules are these:
>
> > $1.$ The person who wins 7 games first wins the total game and gets $20,000$ dollars. 
> > $2.$ If the game stops because of some bad condition, Pascal and Fermat get the price divided by their winning probabilities. 
> > $3. $ Pascal and Fermat have the same skills doing this game.

> Now, Pascal won 5 games, and Fermat won 3. Then, give the price to Pascal and Fermat with the rules above.

I generalized this problem to:

> Fermat won $a$ games, and Pascal won $b$ games. The game with the following rules was stopped by some bad conditions.($b \neq c$) If the price is $d \$$, give Fermat and Pascal each divided price.

```
Rule 1. The person who wins c games first gets the whole price.
Rule 2. If the game stopped before it ended, Fermat and Pascal get the price divided by their winning probability ratios.
Rule 3. No ties happening.
```

As I said above, I tried to solve this with a recurrence sequence.

With some progress, I got:

$$ \text{Fermat takes } d\cdot2^{a+b-2c+1} \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{c-b-1} {{2c-1-a-b} \choose i} \\ 
\text{Pascal takes } d\cdot\biggl\{ 1-2^{a+b-2c+1} \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{c-b-1} {{2c-1-a-b}\choose i} \biggr\}$$

My attempt is a bit long to write down here.

My question is:

1. Is my solution above right?
2. Is there an easier solution than those above?

P.S. This is the solution to the problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Fermat and Pascal playing a game with dollars... You have the sense of humor...

Comment: @JeanMarie Oh, it wasn't intended lol

Comment: Uh... please let me know where should I fix this question if I got downvoted reasonably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the first player who wins $c$ games, wins overall.  Then, you can assume, without loss of generality that $2c-1$ games will be played.  That is, if one of the two players succeeds in winning $c$ games early, continuing the competition anyway to play out $2c-1$ games can **not** alter the overall winner.

Since it is assumed that the first player has won $a$ games and the second player has won $b$ games, there are $(2c-1-a-b)$ games yet to be played.

The first player will win if and only if he wins at least $c-a$ games, which implies that the second player wins no more than $(c-b-1)$ games.

Further, since every game is a coin flip, the [Binomial Distribution Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution),
$~\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{(n-k)}~$ simplifies to replacing the $~\displaystyle p^kq^{(n-k)}~$ expression with $~\dfrac{1}{2^{2c-1-a-b}}.~$

Thus, the first player's chances are

$$\frac{\sum_{k = c-a}^{2c-1-a-b} \binom{2c-1-a-b}{k}}{2^{2c-1-a-b}}.$$